# Application of residue theorem for $x>0$ and $x<0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $\beta>0$ be a constant. I want to show that, for $x>0$,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ikx}}{\beta+ik}\, dk=2\pi e^{-\beta x},
$$
and, for $x<0$,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ikx}}{\beta+ik}\, dk=0.
$$

**(i)**
The integrand has a pole at $k=i\beta$. The idea is to choose $R>\beta$ and to use the Residue theorem:
$$
\int_{-R}^R\frac{e^{ikx}}{\beta+ik}\, dk+\int_{\gamma_R}\frac{e^{izx}}{\beta+iz}\, dz=2\pi i~\text{Res}_{k=i\beta}\left(\frac{e^{ikx}}{\beta+ik}\right)=2\pi e^{-\beta x}
$$
for the semicircular arc $\gamma_R(t):=Re^{it}, t\in [0,\pi]$.

Is there now an easy way to argue that, if $x>0$,
$$
\int_{\gamma_R}\frac{e^{izx}}{\beta+iz}\, dz\to 0\textrm{ as }R\to\infty?
$$

**(ii)**
I think one has to use a similar idea.

Comment: Jordan's lemma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma

Comment: In my example, I have $f(z)=e^{ikx}g(z)$ with $g(z)=\frac{1}{\beta+iz}$. So I need to show that $\lim_{R\to\infty} M_R=0$. Here, I have $M_R=\max_{\theta\in [0,\pi]}\lvert \frac{1}{\beta+i R e^{i\theta}}\rvert$. Don't see that this converges to $0$

Comment: Why don't? $|\beta+iRe^{i\theta}|^2=|\beta+iR\cos\theta-R\sin\theta|^2=|\beta-R\sin\theta|^2+R^2\cos^2\theta=R^2+\beta^2-2\beta R\sin\theta$. $M^2_R<\frac{1}{R^2-2\beta R}=\frac{1}{(R-2\beta)R}\to0$ at $R\to\infty$

Comment: I think, for fixed $R$, $M_R$ is maximal for $\theta\in [0,\pi]$ if $\lvert\beta+Re^{i(\theta+\pi)}\lvert$ is minimal.

Comment: This is correct. That is why I removed positive $\beta^2$ and chose $\sin\theta=1$ (I suppose that $\beta>0$)- to make the inequality stronger

Comment: Ok, I think I got this point. As to (ii), why is this integral 0 if $x<0$? This time Jordan‘s lemma seems not to work I guess. Or DOES it work, when I choose the LOWER semi-circle instead?

Comment: This is also correct. If $x<0$ you choose lower semi-circle (to get vanishing integral along this semi-circle at $R\to\infty$). In this case there are no poles inside the contour, and $I=0$

Comment: How do you get $\lvert\beta+iR\cos\theta-R\sin\theta\rvert^2=\lvert\beta-R\sin\theta\rvert^2+R^2\cos^2\theta =R^2+\beta^2-2\beta R\sin\theta$?

Comment: Ah, I see. Its just the absolute value of complex numbers and you also you $sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$.